# How do you change the "click to edit" column in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

How do you change the "click to edit" column in sharepoint?

Comment: Currently the clickable column is the "Status" column instead of the "Project Title" or "Project Number". So when we see it in reports, we always see stuff like "In QA has been modified" instead of "Foobar feature has been modified"

Answer (score 1):

The definitions for the column live in the View Styles .XML files, changing that means changing the entire installation, you also have Javascript to overlay the actual column or use .NET to create a new column emulating the functionality with your specific rules.